# SSH Password-protected Private Key Still Visible

Tags: osx, ssh-keygen

I thought it was not be possible to view the content of a password-protected private key file without actually inputing a password.

Very surprisingly though, I can still see the content of my private key file even though it's well password-protected. Steps:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -o -a 100
```

I then input my password. I wait a bit. Process is finished, then I do a `cat` as follows:

```
$ cat id_ed25519
```

To my big surprise, I can clearly see my private key.

I wanted to know if it was well password-protected. So, I did the following:

```
$ ssh-keygen -p -f ./id_ed25519
```

Indeed, I have to input my “old” password. Otherwise, it does not recognise it!

Am I missing something? If my understanding is correct, if my private key file is encrypted, I shouldn't see its content in a text editor, right? I'm completely baffled.

System: MacOS Le Capitan, Homebrew

Comment: " I shouldn't see its content in a text editor" is just wrong assumption. Being able to see the content of the file does not mean you can use the file w/o knowing the passphrase used when file was generated. Passphrase is encrypted inside what you see.

Comment: On OS X Le Capitan, quite strangely, killing `ssh-agent` does not prevent from connecting to remote machine without supplying password. One of those peculiarities of Apple in the UNIX worlds… I had to kill all `ssh` processes—using `pgrep ^ssh$; pkill ^ssh$`—so that I'm finally asked to input my password. Now, I'm convinced.

Comment: Perhaps it has to do with `ControlMaster` option of ssh, which when set reuses connection every next time. Instead of killing ssh process, you can try `ssh -O stop user@rhost` command to check that.

Comment: **1 / 3** – Using SSH option `-O` is indeed a more elegant way to terminate the background connexion than resorting to the big artillery. Setting `ControlMaster`-related `ControlPersist` option to `no` will require typing the passphrase to initiate a new SSH connexion if any previous SSH connexion has been terminated. In fact, as read from other sources, in order to avoid typing the password every time before initiating a new SSH connexion, `ControlMaster auto` must be set.

Comment: **2 / 3** – If `ControlPersist yes` is set, then a new SSH connexion can be made without typing the passphrase even though any previous SSH connexion has been terminated; if `ControlPersist no` is set, then a new SSH connexion can be made, again without inputting the password, provided there still exists at least one live SSH connexion.

Comment: **3 / 3** – In a way, both `ControlMaster auto` and `ControlPersist yes` are somewhat equivalent to the nice [*Keychain*](https://www.funtoo.org/Keychain) script, which relies on both `ssh-add` and `ssh-agent`. **Note:** tunnelling (port forwarding) with `ControlMaster` enabled is not a good idea; use `-o ControlMaster=no` or `ControlMaster no` in a local config for port forwarding on a specific host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between an encrypted key (which is password protected) and a non-encrypted key.  All keys are still plaintext files.  Below I have generated a key, with no password, and then secured it by adding a password, and you can see how the contents of the file on disk is different:

```
$ ssh-keygen -f ./id_example
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in ./id_example.
Your public key has been saved in ./id_example.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:q1soNjAdOS7sEu/268wb/F0ULMB7a2tmr/n+089Ksu0 user@host
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 2048]----+
|     ..          |
|     ... .       |
|    +  .. o      |
| . o o. .. .     |
|. = o  .S..      |
| + =   .oo       |
|. o * ..o.. ...  |
| o.+ = +=o  .=.. |
| ..oBo+=+=+.ooEoo|
+----[SHA256]-----+
$ cat id_example
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEogIBAAKCAQEArxyeUk2lJ+pkW2bHXJNFUfWz1z3glvOsHSUxUQjx8leKIKRu
[hash truncated fro brevity]
hGWfADUrb5nV5Do/mcjBHQDCjrfCpzPHkNrTaZLs4JDxdhX4G0s=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
$ ssh-keygen -p -f ./id_example
Enter new passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved with the new passphrase.
$ cat id_example
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,764EDE56E9A89905CD447F1DEF5ED1AB

uVjfs7qu4a7RMvycvpvtJA0UUG5UtkZ+eY6ppmxL7oA/54qM/7S5bvgOT1hM0wL+
[hash truncated for brevity]
FHCAmqC29+FPHxqG19tII7ndYYU6YDpCQHjUN0TaAI7ikwSmjTiNBfXEZodaHblr
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The actual *key* is the same, but a key agent will not be able to *use* the latter key until I unlock it with my passphrase.  Either way, I own the file, and it has to exist on disk which means it *can* be displayed (e. g. with `cat`).

You can also see when I display the revised key that it explicitly shows that it is encrypted.

Comment: I did repeat your set of commands. In my case as well, the content of the file is different when setting a password. However, the layout of the output for the password-protected version remains exactly the same with no mention it's actually encrypted in the header. In other words, no `Proc-Type: …` and no `DEK-Info:` in the file for the password-protected version. Furthermore, when `ssh-copy-id` to server, and later connecting to it via this password-protected key, I can connect to server without supplying any password at all. So, I'm still stuck in my understanding…

Comment: I'm using `OpenSSH_7.8p1` Could someone using this version tell me whether `ssh-keygen` provides both `Proc-Type: …` and `DEK-Info: …` for the password-protected key file? I don't seem to have this kind of header. However, using an older version of OpenSSH (6.9), I do have these headers.

Comment: Apparently, that's OK. Even though there's no header, private key is still encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

You will always be able to (and need to) 'see' the contents of your private key file but it's encrypted so it should appear to be gibberish.  What you need to make sure of is that only *you* (i.e. your user id) can see it.  To do that you need to:

```
chmod go-rwx ./id_ed25519
```

Also, you'll probably want to keep your private keys in their own directory so that you can chmod the directory as well.

Comment: What's the point then of “encrypting” a private key file? Does that only mean I have to input the recorded password when connecting to the server?

Comment: The purpose to password-protecting a key is to make is such that the key's owner can be certain that only they are the one to actually _use_ the key after it has been generated.  A passwordless key can authenticate Alice as Bob _if_ Alice somehow gets ahold of Bob's private key.

Comment: Exactly, the passphrase 'unlocks' the private key.  This provides a bit of extra protection should anyone ever get access to the private key file.  So let's say you walk away from your computer and someone else sits down and tries to ssh/whatever using your private key. Without the passphrase, they won't get very far (though if they make a copy of it they could brute-force the passphrase:  it's a bit of extra protection, not absolute protection)  Desktop key managers will often offer to keep keys 'unlocked' for some period of time/duration of login session as a convenience.

Comment: Also note that the password in these cases is entirely local and used to unlock the _key_; the password has no part in the authentication to the remote host whatsoever; all the remote host sees is the key itself.

Comment: Refering to @blihp [Keychain](https://www.funtoo.org/Keychain) seems to be a great tool for convenient use of password-protected private keys…